# Purpose/use of procedures that take an arbitrary amount of arguments?

Tags: lambda, scheme

In class (scheme) we recently learned about the syntax that allows a function to take an arbitrary amount of arguments eg;

```
(define len
  (lambda args
    (length args)))

>(len 1 2 3)
3
```

What are the advantages of using this form over simply passing the arguments as a single list in the first place? How do you even pass arguments to these kinds of functions within a program (and not on the command line)? Is there a way to make a procedure that returns a series of values that aren't wrapped within a list?

Comment: One very useful example is `(define (list . elements) elements)` (also written as `(define list (lambda elements elements))`.  Variadic functions are also handy for naturally n-ary functions.  E.g., if you already have a binary addition function, you can do `(define + (lambda addends (foldl add2 0 addends)))`.

Answer (score 2):

### Variadic functions

One very useful example is

```
(define (list . elements) elements)
; or
(define list (lambda elements elements))
```

Variadic functions are also handy for functions that are naturally *n*-ary functions.  E.g., if you already have a binary addition function `add2`, you can do

```
(define + (lambda addends (foldl add2 0 addends)))
; or
(define (+ . addends) (foldl add2 0 addends))
```

In addition to calling these like

```
(+ 1 2 3)
;=> 6
```

you can also use `apply` when you already have the arguments in a list:

```
(apply + '(1 2 3))
;=> 6
```

One advantage to this is making it easier to write functions that use a different argument convention.  I don't know if this is particularly common in Scheme, but you could use this to take keyword/named arguments.  E.g., instead of defining

```
(define (subseq lst start end) ...)
```

where you'll always have to provide start and end arguments, you could do

```
(define (subseq lst . args) ...)
```

so that `lst` is always necessary, but args could or could not contain start and end arguments.  You could use this to implement default values.  E.g.,

```
(subseq lst 'start 3 'end 6) ; specify both expllicitly
(subseq lst 'end 6)          ; default value for start, e.g., 0
(subseq lst 'start 4)        ; default value of end, e.g., length of list
(subseq lst)                 ; default for both, copy the list
```

You'd have to write the code to extract the specified or default values, but that's not too hard.

### Multiple values

As to returning multiple values, you can return multiple values using the aptly named `values`:

```
(values 1 2 3)
;=> 1
;=> 2
;=> 3
```

but that's really unrelated to functions that take an arbitrary number of arguments, because those are tied in with lists, and `values` isn't really about lists.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can return multiple values using the `values` procedure, and you can pass arbitrary arguments to a procedure using `apply`. But your course may not have taught those concepts yet. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Assume you have the following two 'len' functions:

```
(define len1
  (lambda args (length args)))

(define len2
  (lambda (lst) (length lst)))
```

You would invoke these as:

```
> (len1 1 2 3)
3
> (len2 (list 1 2 3)
3
```

As you can see there is not much of a difference.  In the case of `len2` you created the list; in the case of `len1` the compiler created the list.  Arguably the compiler could be a tiny bit more efficient.

Lets assume you already have a list that you want to take the length of.  For these two you'd use:

```
> (define l '(1 2 3))
> (apply len1 l)
3
> (len2 l)
3
; note
> (len1 l)
1
```

The `apply` function takes a list for its second argument and 'presents' the list elements as arguments to its first argument (`len1` in this case).

If you don't want to return a list but do want to return multiple value you'd use `values` as

```
(define my-return-3-values-function
  (lambda (a b c)
    (values a b c)))
```